# What to pass as parameters to constructor from super class

Tags: java, constructor, polymorphism, abstract-class

I'm making an `abstract super` `Item` class, but I'm not sure where to put as the parameters for this constructor. This is because an `Item` is made up of different subjects, i.e. `Course`, `Student`, which will have different parameters.

The constructor for a `Course` will be

```
public Course(String courseName, int courseNum)
{
     super();
     this.courseNum = courseNum;
     this.courseName = courseName;
}
```

and the constructor for a `Student` will be

```
public Student(int studentID, String studentName)
{
    super();
    this.studentName = studentName;
    this.studentID = studentID;
}
```

So right now my `super()` constructor `Item` does not accept any parameters, but this can't be right either. I've tried to look up this subject, but it seems to only give examples where all variables from the `super` class were used.

Comment: Can you explain how both a `Student` and a `Course` can be considered an `Item`? What is common about them that you need them to extend the same abstract base class?

Comment: @Jason, They're both subclasses of `Item` because eventually all `Items` will be put into an arbitrary `List`

Comment: @user180708 Just to be able to put everything in a list you do not need a superclass. You could just as well create a List<Object> and you would be able to put you objects in it. It would not make much sense, though.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely common that an abstract super class does not take constructor parameters. However you should also consider in this case, that what you really need is a common interface, not a superclass.

You should think about how you will use an `Item` object and how you will use a `Student` object. Think through, what is an `Item` in your application, what attributes it has etc. This will lead you to a proper class design.

Item should incorporate common attributes of the subclasses. I am afraid, you  want to inappropriately apply inheritance, since courses and students do not have much in common. Say, you wanted to have a class `Teacher` and a class `Student` then the common superclass could be `Person` which would contain the gender, age, name etc.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking that my abstract super class needed constructor parameters, in case I want to create getter/setter methods for the `Item` class. But could I just use the getter/setter methods for the subclasses and then cast it to an `Item`?

Comment: I updated my answer. I suggest you thinking about the problem more in depth. Inheritance should rarely be used, only in cases when the superclass can be considered as a generalisation of the subclass (eg. Person is a generalisation of Teacher and Student).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think inheritance is the right choice here, unless you really desperately need to have a mixing of Courses and Students in a single list structure, in which case I would really like to see what it is you're even doing.

If you have no commonalities between the objects, they should not share a common superclass.  Based on the parameters in those constructors, the objects have nothing in common.  Therefore, you should not be making a superclass that joins them.

So the reason you're finding that there are no examples where the subclasses don't use any variables from a superclass is because a superclass is not supposed to do that.

For instance, `Circle` and `Square` as subclasses of `Shape` (this last one probably being an interface), but not `Wheel` and `Person_Named_Carl` as subclasses of `Generic_Thing`.  There's nothing in common between wheels and people named Carl, except that they are all `Object`s anyway.

Think about whether you NEED this superclass.  If you do, you need to figure out how to not need it, because that's really, really, not how inheritance is supposed to work.  Separate your Big Giant List Of Things into lists for each of the classes you have, maybe.